# Awaiting AWS EC2 instance stop or start completion

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I would like to send a request through the AWS EC2 API to stop (or start) an instance and then get a callback when the machine is in the `stopped` state (or `running`).

I'm using the AWS SDK for .NET, and I've tried the `ec2Client.StopInstancesAsync` method. It returns as soon as the request has posted, so it **does not** make an asynchronous callback after the state transition.

What I'm aiming to do overall is to stop an instance, change the `InstanceType` once the machine is `stopped`, then start the instance. It appears the only way to do this might be to make the stop request, start my own polling mechanism to watch the instance state transition to `stopped`, then continue with the `InstanceType` change once it has completed.

I'd love to think there's a simpler, less chatty way of waiting for the transition to complete. Does anyone know of a way to be notified when an EC2 state transition has completed?

Comment: `StopInstancesAsync` returns a Task<T>. You need to await it using async / await, or use a continuation, or however you want to do it.

Comment: Yes... this is what I was trying with `StopInstancesAsync`, but when I did get the response back after the await, it was a simple `StopInstancesResponse` (i.e. the same thing as the standard `StopInstances` call returns). It does not await the completion, only the request.

Comment: A Rest API call does not wait for it to be stopped before returning, instead you need to poll for the status at some interval.

Comment: I think a better, cloud-centric approach would be to terminate the current instance and start a brand new one using the new instance type. Don't get attached to your instances, they should be disposable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is no. There appears to be no way to be notified when an EC2 instance transition has completed. Polling is the way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to verify the state except polling. The reason behind is that the reply for API stop request does not contain the confirmation for instance state. So there is nothing you can do about it.