# Google Cloud Engine - Is there a callback when instance creation is complete when done through the API?

Tags: php, api, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform

Hi Google Cloud Engine experts,

I'm trying to figure out if a callback can be setup to be called upon completion of instance creation on GCE via the API.

My application currently uses AWS EC2 instances and I have to poll several times a minute to update the status of my VMs.

I know from [Awaiting AWS EC2 instance stop or start completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636689/awaiting-aws-ec2-instance-stop-or-start-completion) that callback doesn't exist in EC2.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Could you specify the API call you are using to create instances?

Comment: What would you want to do upon completion of instance creation? In fact, every mutation request in GCE is asynchronous and returns an Operation object. You can poll that Operation object for completion and error status.